# Run python script from another computer without installing packages/setting up environment?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, package, environment-variables, virtual-environment

I have a Jupyter notebook script that will be used to teach others how to use python.

Instead of asking each participant to install the required packages, I would like to provide a folder with the environment ready from the start.

How can I do this?

What is the easiest way to teach python without running into technical problems with packages/environments etc.?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to install Python dependencies, you can use @Aero Blue solution. However, the users would need probably to make a virtual environment, so they don't mess with other environments and versions, etc.
However, if they should need some Linux packages, this would not be enough. Therefore, I would suggest using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). You would need to provide them with a Dockerfile, that you should set to install any dependencies (whether is for Python or Linux), and they would just need to use *docker build* and *docker run* commands.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I have found to package python files is to use `pyinstaller` which packages your python file into an executable file.

If it's a single file I usually run `pyinstaller main.py --onefile`

Another option is to have a `requirements` file

This reduces installing all packages to one command `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I tried this but realised this is what I need. I want the participants to just install the packages and be able to edit the script

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use a program such as py2exe, pyinstaller, or cx_freeze to package each the file, the modules, and a lightweight interpreter. The result will be an executable which does not require the user to have any modules or even python installed to access it; however, because of the built-in interpreter, it can get quite large (which is why Python is not commonly used to make executables).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Azure notebooks or another Jupyter hosting service ? Most of these have a special syntax you can use to perform pip installs. For Azure it is `!pip install`

https://notebooks.azure.com